# Закрытие программы

Tags: vb.net

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы при нажатие на кнопку программа закрывалась совсем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close() сработает ТОЛЬКО в случае, если контекст выполнения находится в главной форме. А вообще вот:

```
Application.Exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Me.Close()
```